# Perl system + split + array

Tags: perl, split

my name is luis, live in arg.
i have a problem, which can not solve.

```
**IN BASH**
pwd
/home/labs-perl
ls
file1.pl file2.pl

**IN PERL**
my $ls = exec("ls");
my @lsarray = split(/\s+/, $ls);
print "$lsarray[1]\n"; #how this, i need the solution. >> file.pl
file1.pl file2.pl # but this is see in shell.
```

Comment: If you would `use warnings`, perl would warn you that nothing after the `exec()` would be executed.  (*"Statement unlikely to be reached at ..."*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output you see is not from the print statement, it is the console output of `ls`. To get the `ls` output into a variable, use backticks:

```
my $ls = `ls`;
my @lsarray = split(/\s+/, $ls);
print "$lsarray[1]\n";
```

This is because `exec` does not return, the statements after it are not executed. From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

> The exec function executes a system command and never returns; use
>   system instead of exec if you want it to return. It fails and returns
>   false only if the command does not exist and it is executed directly
>   instead of via your system's command shell

But using `system` command will not help you as it does not allow output capturing, hence, the backticks. However, using `glob` functions is better:

```
my @arr = glob("*");
print $arr[1], "\n";
```

Also, perl array indices start at 0, not 1. To get file1.pl you should use `print "$lsarray[0]\n"`.

Answer (score 3):

It is bad practice to use the shell when you can write something within Perl.

This program displays what I think you want.

```
chdir '/home/labs-perl' or die $!;
my @dir = glob '*';
print "@dir\n";
```

---

**Edit**

I have just understood better what you need from perreal's post.

To display the first file in the current working directory, just write

```
print((glob '*')[0], "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print <*> // die("No file found\n"), "\n";
```

(Though using an iterator in scalar context should usually be avoided if the script will be doing anything further.)